# Are vCPU the same as 1 Socket, or a single Core?

Tags: vps, sql, vcpu

Currently I have a Hyper-v VPS with 2 (vCPU) processor.  I would like to install SQL Server Express 2012 that has a limitation of 1 Socket or 4 Cores, whichever the lesser.

**My Question:** Are vCPU's counted as a single core, or as sockets? or something completely different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hyper-V presents one socket with multiple cores.

You can verify this with a tool such as [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/downloads/cpu-z/1.60.1-64bits-en.zip). Here's a screenshot I took of a 2-vCPU Hyper-V guest I have:

[image]

For what it's worth, VMWare ESXi permits you to choose your mix of sockets/cores vCPUs.

### I am not a lawyer, so stop reading now

Installing SQL Express on a machine that violates the license simply means (as far as I can tell) that the SQL instance will not utilise the extra power of the server. For example, it's limited to *x* gigs of ram, but if you install it in a server with 256Gb of RAM, it will just neglect to use the rest.

Comment: Awesome Thanks,  Didn't think to Run CPUZ.

Comment: No worries. there are ways to query WMI to get the info manually, but CPU-Z is basically easier to use and understand.